# Why is my navbar from React-Bootstrap rendering vertically and not the way displayed in the documentation?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, reactjs

I have tried to import my navbar class from bootstrap into my new react app, but it doesn't render as intended. [Instead of rendering in the same row, it renders like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bZbF0.png)

Here is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Navbar, Nav, NavItem, MenuItem, NavDropdown } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

export default class SplashNav extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Navbar>
        <Navbar.Header>
          <Navbar.Brand>
            <a href="#home">React-Bootstrap</a>
          </Navbar.Brand>
        </Navbar.Header>
        <Nav>
          <NavItem eventKey={1} href="#">
            Link
         </NavItem>
          <NavItem eventKey={2} href="#">
            Link
    </NavItem>
          <NavDropdown eventKey={3} title="Dropdown" id="basic-nav-dropdown">
            <MenuItem eventKey={3.1}>Action</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem eventKey={3.2}>Another action</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem eventKey={3.3}>Something else here</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem divider />
            <MenuItem eventKey={3.4}>Separated link</MenuItem>
          </NavDropdown>
        </Nav>
      </Navbar>
    )
  }
}
```

and

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Jumbotron, Grid, Row, Col, Image, Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
import './SplashScreen.css';
import SplashNav from './SplashNav.js';

export default class SplashScreen extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <SplashNav />
        <Grid>
          <Jumbotron>
            <h2>Welcome to Vocafy</h2>
            <p>This is how to communicate with your people</p>
          </Jumbotron>
          <Link to="/login">
            <Button bsStyle="primary">Login</Button>  
          </Link>  
        </Grid>
      </div> 
    )
  }
}
```

I read the Bootstrap documentation and I should have all of the necessary CDNs, etc. Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]The navbar looks OK when I run your code.  Double check that you are linking to the bootstrap .css correctly in your public index.html.  In testing your code I used:

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

If that isn't your problem then try rendering the component without importing `SplashScreen.css`.  Perhaps you have some styles in there that are overriding the bootstrap.

Comment: Just checked and it seems like I was using the Bootstrap 4 link. That and removing and reinstalling react-bootstrap seemed to help. Thank you!